# How to let not rotated text follow a rotated div?

Tags: html, css, rotation

I'm having a problem for which I couldn't find a solution. I want to rotate a div element which contains text. The text shouldn't be rotated though, but must be contained in the div. This is how it looks now. Sadly I cannot post an image of how it should look, because I'm too newbie :(

```css
.text{
 width:320px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
p{
 -ms-transform: rotate(15deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><p>Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder !</p></div>
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried defining the p position as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible with CSS transformations (as you have seen), instead you should look at [shape-inside](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes). This will let you define a shame that you want the text to be contained in. However as you can see from the link, support isn't great at this time. Would SVG be a better solution? Here is an example of this approach ([source](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/)):

```
shape-inside: circle(160px at 400px 60px);
```

There is also a [tool](http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/) that you can use to build arbitrary polygons for this CSS feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will stick will stick with the SVG, since I want my website to be compatible with all browser.